# Setting root without password only for a single database

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

How to configure mysql [using phpmyadmin ?] to use one database by the root user without password ?

I have the root user with password. I need the root to access one database without password.

Comment: You probably don't need root, but an user with all privileges on that specific database.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to do that. A MySQL user is defined by a combination of host+username+password (not a database name).

Create another MySQL user. In the current phpMyAdmin version, this can be done via the Users menu.

By the way, it's not secure to have a username without password.